# How to find a time is one hour before and within my custom time in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to start download exactly one hour before or within my custom time. 
For example I should start to download at 7 AM or with 8 AM (8 AM is my custom time). How I can achieve this. the following is my code,

```
AppDelegate * iDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    iDelegate.mStartTime = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:START_TIME];
    int stHr = [[[iDelegate.mStartTime componentsSeparatedByString:@":"] objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
    int stMin = [[[iDelegate.mStartTime componentsSeparatedByString:@":"] objectAtIndex:1] intValue];
    int formStTime = (stHr*60)+stMin;
    NSDate *today = [[[NSDate alloc] init]autorelease];

    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar]autorelease];
    NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init]autorelease];
    [offsetComponents setHour:+1];
    NSDate *modifiedDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:today options:0];
    NSDateComponents * timecomponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:(NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:modifiedDate];

    NSInteger currentHour = [timecomponents hour];
    NSInteger currtMin = [timecomponents minute];
    int nowTime = (currentHour*60)+currtMin;
    if (nowTime <= formStTime || nowTime >= formStTime)
    {
        // start download
    }
```

But I should not download if the current time is 8 AM or after 8 AM . 
What is the mistake in my code ? Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "custom time"?

Comment: I am having the common time in my app that I should stop downloading at 8 AM daily which I called as custom time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not considered in detail all your code's logic, but this struck to me:

```
if (nowTime <= formStTime || nowTime >= formStTime)
```

this condition will be always true. This explains why your code is not working as you wish since it should always do the downloading, even after 8AM. You are after a condition link this:

```
if (nowTime >= minimumTime || nowTime < maximumTime)
```

However, I have not clear from your question how you define `minimum` and `maximumTime` so cannot advise further. If `formStTime` is your `minimumTime` and we assume that `maximumTime` is just one hour later, you could have:

```
if (nowTime >= formStTime || nowTime < formStTime + 60)
```

(If I read correctly your code.)

EDIT: after your clarification in the comments, the condition to start the download would be:

```
if (nowTime < formStTime)
  //-- start download
```

To handle the second part of your requirements (stopping the download at the given maximum time) you will need a different logic altogether. One way of doing it would be starting a `NSTimer` when you start a download that will fire at the right time; then, you would check if the download is still going on and stop it. A `NSTimer` is just one of multiple possibilities you have (you could also use `displatch_after`), but the basic idea will not change.

E.g.:

```
if (nowTime < formStTime) {

    //--= start download

    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(formStTime - nowTime)*60 //-- seconds
   target:self
   selector:@selector(timeExpired:)
   userInfo:nil
   repeats:NO];
}
```

then in the handler function:

```
- (void)timeExpired:(NSTimer*)timer {

       if (downloadStillOngoing)
         //-- stop the download

}
```

When your download is done, you should call `[self.timer invalidate]`, also.

However, you will need to fill a number of gaps in my sketch implementation to get to a working solution. If you need more help about stopping the download, you will need to provide more information about how you are doing the download and possibly ask a new question.

Comment: Yes it always returns true, then how I can check nowtime is exactly one hour before or within my custom time ?

Comment: please, have a look at my edit. if that does not help, how do you define your custom time?

Comment: For example, if my custom time is 8 am daily, I need to start the download before 8 AM or within 8 AM. If my current time is 8 AM I need to stop the download.

Comment: so, you want to start the download if the current time is earlier than 8AM. furthermore, you want to stop an already started download at 8AM (if it has not finished yet). Is this right?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I should download only one hour (7 AM) before my custom or start time (8 AM). But your condition (nowtime < stTime)will fail if my current time 6 AM right ?

Comment: I think you are representing nowTime and stTime in minutes, so the `<` condition will fail at 7:00; on the other hand, 6:59 should give you 6 * 60 + 59 < 7 * 60. Does that makes sense? If you prefer working with hours instead, it should be nowTime <= stTime.

Comment: I prefer to work with minutes. Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Modify your if condition with below code:

```
if (nowTime >= formStTime && nowTime <= formStTime + 60)
```